# ¿Existe una forma de que el código compilado de Typescript use sintaxis ES6?

Tags: typescript, es6

Llevo algún tiempo aprendiendo Java y me gustan los lenguajes de tipado estático, por lo cual quiero seguir haciéndolo con JavaScript. El "problema" es que me gusta el código de JavaScript ES6, que permite usar variables de tipo "const" y "let" así como arrow functions.

Typescript te permite hacer todo esto, pero me parece terrible que el código compilado use sintáxis antigua.

Por ejemplo:

Typescript:

```
const staticallyTyped = (name: string): string =>
    "You are better of learning your types, " + name + "!";
```

Código de JavaScript que esperaría:

```
const staticallyTyped = (name) =>
    "You are better of learning your types, " + name + "!";
```

Código de JavaScript compilado:

```
var staticallyTyped = function (name) {
    return "You are better of learning your types, " + name + "!";
};
```

¿Hay alguna forma de que el código compilado de JavaScript use sintaxis ES6?

Comment: Hola ManuAlvarado22, ¿podrías decirnos cómo estás compilando TS? Saludos.

Comment: Saludos Jesús.
Installé TS con npm y lo compilo escribiendo tsc app.ts

Answer (score 4, accepted):

De acuerdo a la [respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35431571/1595451) a Can TypeScript compile to ES6 code?

Agregar lo siguiente a la línea de comandos

```
--target es6
```

Comment: Worked like a charm!
Muchas gracias Rubén.

Answer (score 1):

Usando el compilador de TypeScript, únicamente hay que agregar la opción `--target ES2015` en los argumentos del script.

---

Para más información, te recomiendo que veas el siguiente enlace:

- https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html

Comment: Muchas gracias Jesús. Rubén respondió un poco antes, pero ambas resolvieron mi duda.